# TableWidget "Enter" keypressed current text

Tags: python, pyside

I am using python, Pyside2 on my interface.

I have a tableWidget and I want to get current text after press enter.
So I have below codes:

I add below function in to current page open:

```
self.ui.edit_table.keyPressEvent = self.KeyPressed
```

Then I add below function:

```
def KeyPressed(self, event):
    if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Return:
        print('Enter Key Pressed')
        self.ui.edit_table.setEditTriggers(QtWidgets.QTableWidget.CurrentChanged)
        print(self.ui.edit_table.item(0, 1).text())
        newListValues = []
        for i in range(0, 46):
            newListValues.append(self.ui.edit_table.item(i, 1).text())
        print(newListValues)
        newListValues.clear()
```

When I change the value, and press the enter I see `Enter Key Pressed` but I couldnt see new value. But if I press the enter button one more without any changing, I can see new values in newListValue. Why the new value shows me with delay ?

For example item(0, 1) value is 5, when I change this value to 12 and press enter I couldnt see any changing in             `print(self.ui.edit_table.item(0, 1).text())` but when I press enter again I can see 12 value.

Why this happening ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When pressing <kbd>Return</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd> during the editing state, the data is not instantly submitted to the model.

The key press event is handled by the delegate editor (usually, the line edit) which will eventually validate or fixup the entered value and, finally, submit the data.

If you want to know when data has *actually* changed, connect to the [`itemChanged`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#itemChanged) signal.

Also note that:

- "patching" event handlers like this is discouraged, as often leads to silent errors or mishandled events (since the scope of the function is not the instance of the class that should handle the event); you either use an event filter, or a promoted widget;
- you should always call the base implementation of the event handler, unless you're completely sure that you don't want to handle it; for instance, in your case your implementation completely prevents keyboard navigation or the possibility to enter the edit mode by pressing <kbd>Return</kbd> or <kbd>F2</kbd>;